# How to make nice race game camera?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I have recently begun to make a racing game, but I need the camera to follow car like in other games - currently, when I steer my car the camera immediately follows it and I can see only the back of car, but I want it so that while you steer, you can see side of car too, like here:

[image]

How can I create something like this?

Comment: If you could show what you currently have, preferably with a blend file uploaded to http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ that would be better, thanks.

Comment: https://vimeo.com/115065397 video will be aviable after 40 minutes since now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78ORdi4-ynk I found answer here...:) This really does work for me! So, what did I do wrong: I parented camera to car. And, what is appropirate for this game: Selecting camera, adding Always sensor, And controller and Camera actuator with car object selected, min and max to 10, height to 3 and damp to 0.05. Hope this helps you too

Comment: Could you please add some more details that you got from the link, link only answers aren't really very helpful.

Comment: OK! Editing now!

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using the *Slow Parent* option.
Set an appropriate offset, and the parented object (in this case it is your camera) will always have that much delay to reach its target position. This provides for smoother parents and a side view when turning more reliably than using the *Camera* actuator. When using the *Camera* actuator, It does not behave as expected when the object it is following moves in the direction of the camera (for example, when the character is backing up)
using this method, you can have one camera for driving forward, and one camera for backing up, and both will reliably look where they are meant to.

[image]